# Google Sheets API- How do I append new rows on TOP of table?(Android)

Tags: java, android, google-sheets-api

In my Android App, I would like to append a row (with new food order information) to the top of a google sheets table. From the https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/append documentation it sounds like I'm only able to append to the bottom of a table. But I realy need to append the new row from TOP, and I doubt that's impossible.
I was able to append rows to the bottom, using this code:

```
String ORDER_SHEET_ID = "<my speardsheet id here>";
String ORDERS_RANGE_DINING = "DiningOrders!C5:I";
//...                       
this.mService.spreadsheets().values().append(ORDER_SHEET_ID,ORDERS_RANGE_DINING, body)
.setValueInputOption("RAW").setInsertDataOption("INSERT_ROWS").execute();
```

Is it possible to append the row to the top of the table? How? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use to insert a new row.  It creates the row and uses the paste command to set the data so I can do everything in one HTTP round trip.  Alternatively you could update the data using a second request if you want.  I'm not sure if the Paste command can insert rows or not, but this works.

```
InsertDimensionRequest insertRow = new InsertDimensionRequest();
insertRow.setRange(new DimensionRange().setDimension("ROWS").setStartIndex(0).setEndIndex(1).setSheetId(sheetId));
PasteDataRequest data = new PasteDataRequest().setData("Data").setDelimiter("\t")
        .setCoordinate(new GridCoordinate().setColumnIndex(0).setRowIndex(0).setSheetId(sheetId));

BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest r = new BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest().setRequests(Arrays.asList(
        new Request().setInsertDimension(insertRow),
        new Request().setPasteData(data)
        ));
BatchUpdateSpreadsheetResponse response = this.mService.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(SHEET_ID, r).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [thread](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/94687/127590).

> In case if you need to add a new row on top (first row) and copy
>   formula from the first top row then you'll need to copy formulas
>   across using `getFormulas()` and `setFormulas()` functions. You can
>   change the value of `firstRow` to 2 if your spreadsheet has headers
>   for example.
>
> ```
> function addFirstRow() {
>     var firstRow = 1;
>     var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
>     var lCol = sh.getLastColumn();
>     var range = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
>     var formulas = range.getFormulas();
>     sh.insertRowsAfter(1, 1);
>     newRange = sh.getRange(firstRow, 1, 1, lCol);
>     newRange.setFormulas(formulas);
> }
> ```

You may also check this thread: [Having new entries show up top in google sheets.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/V_UVuwX_UFY)